# Is there a current in this situation?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If a wire moves through a magnetic field a current is induced in the wire.

If you drop a piece of wire through a magnetic field, the wire is of a finite length and the whole length is shorter than the span of the field and because it is dropped is not earthed thus the current has only a limited length to flow and has nowhere to escape does the magnetic field still create a current in the wire?

Comment: Induction only creates a current when the circuit is closed.

Comment: Is there force on the charge carriers? Can they move? How much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you mentioned, if your "wire" is simply a straight or non-closed conductor
**an emf gets generated across the ends of the conductor,known as motional emf**

*Do note that this is not equivalent to a current getting generated.*

This emf gets generated in equilibrium conditions ,when the electric field force balances the magnetic field force on the charged particles within the conductor.

Due to magnetic force charges start moving in the conductor.In equilibrium,force of electric field balances the force of magnetic field.Let induced electric field be E1

then,

qv*B  + qE1 = 0

=> E1 = -v*B

Now, potential difference developed across the ends of condcutor,
V(at b) - V(at a) =  \int_a^b (v*B) dl

If the circuit is incomplete then terminal potential difference will be equal to emf induced.,but no current will flow within the wire.

[image]

If however,the circuit is made complete as below,a current will indeed flow,and we can view this conducting rod in this case as a cell of emf equal to the induced emf.

[image]

Thus, for a current to flow, you need to have a "complete" circuit.Otherwise,in an open circuit such as this simply an emf gets generated.
the fact that current does not flow is also supported by the fact that the Electric field in this case is conservative,created by charge-separation.this is what allowed us determine the terminal pd by line integral of conservative E field over dl.